# Create Website that behaves more like a desktop application with windows and dragging of assets between the windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a website front page which behaves more like an actual desktop application with windows and ability to drag and drop assets from one window to the next (and untop of other items on another windows).

This is very easily done in a desktop application. How can we replicate it using on a website?

I know I can do jquery such as this: http:// jsfiddle.net/4Vfm5/1095/
to resize and move an image.

What I want to do is make the website behave more like an application with windows. I am not as concerned about mobile applications as website viewed via desktop computer.

**Are there any frameworks that help the process?**

I have seen some site that behave that way (using "Div"s for each window) - but I gather they used a lot of custom code to make it look like that. I am trying to see if there are packages that help the process along?

This is how I want the webpage to look like
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_FN5UlpyrboVU9WZzFRdGl6TlE/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much.

Jack

Comment: you can drag assets in JS using "html5 drag and drop", google it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have these links a read before posting a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. This question (to me) appears off-topic as you are asking for a framework (software library), and is too broad otherwise .

Answer (score 2):

One you can try is Ext JS:
http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs

Depending on your use case you may need to pay them (I think if you use it for a commercial purpose).  But it supports Layout and Controls similar to the type of design you would expect from a desktop UI framework.  It also has drag and drop support built in.